# Troublesome two lines of Java script in a SharePoint link?

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer, javascript

I'm getting an IE error with these lines of code:

```
<a href="javascript: return false;" onmouseover="window.status='{@EncodedAbsUrl}';  
return true" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true" 
onclick="javascript:createNewDocumentWithProgID
('{@EncodedAbsUrl}', '', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', false);"><xsl:value-of 
select="@FileLeafRef" /></a>
```

Error reads "'return' statement outside of function". (It's non-intrusive - just the yellow triangle in the bottom of the browser window.)

I know very little about javascript, so I'm hesistant to correct. Any thoughts, guys?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
<a href="#" ...
```

Comment: Scott, thank you very much for your answer! That little tip helps me and my coworkers immensely - I hope karma rewards you well for your kindness! THANKS AGAIN!! :D

Comment: @Ryan, if that worked for you can you check the check mark next to the answer so I get credit.